# Interfaces in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface

I want some interfaces used in selenium webDriver.
WebDriver itself is one of the interface. can we list down some more?

Comment: So can you share your list please?

Comment: i dont have much idea.. webelement is another one which i found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find list of all `RemoteWebDriver` implemented interfaces in the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html)

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>
> HasCapabilities, HasInputDevices,
> Interactive, FindsByClassName, FindsByCssSelector, FindsById,
> FindsByLinkText, FindsByName, FindsByTagName, FindsByXPath,
> JavascriptExecutor, SearchContext, TakesScreenshot, WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver itself is an interface. There are a couple of interfaces in Selenium. A few of them are as below:

1. Alert
2. Capabilities
3. ContextAware
4. HasCapabilities
5. JavascriptExecutor
6. OutputType
7. Rotatable
8. SearchContext
9. TakesScreenshot
10. WebDriver
11. WebDriver.ImeHandler
12. WebDriver.Navigation
13. WebDriver.Options
14. WebDriver.TargetLocator
15. WebDriver.Timeouts
16. WebDriver.Window
17. WebElement
18. WrapsDriver
19. WrapsElement

You can further refer to the Selenium Java docs for more info [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/)